# Logging user login date and time in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, openid-connect

I am trying to log user login date and time to the database. I am using OpenId Connect authentication and the token is valid for 20 mins.

For the first time user comes to the application I am logging date and time in the SecurityTokenValidated event. But If the user close the browser and return to the application with in 20 mins (before the token expires) this even will not fire as there is no authentication performs with OpenId provider.

I thought I can use PostAuthenticateRequest in Global.asax but this even fires several time and for every page.

What is the best place to do this?

Comment: I am not experienced in this area, but I have few thoughts. How do you define when the user came back? Can you fire the SecurityTokenValidated event manually? If you could define that the user came back, you could manually fire this event.

Comment: Start of a new "session" can be treated as user returning to the application. Ideally Session_Start would me my ideal place to log but this event fires before the authentication request.